# Texturing/UV wrap help

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I need help with lining up some things for my model when using the UV wrap. I have attached what the model looks like and the texture I want to apply to it. Is there an way to do it that a beginner could understand or would it be a bit difficult?[image: I just done this with a smart uv project and a quick paste of a candy cane colour and pattern]

Answer (score 2):

### First, some general UV unwrapping tips

If you want to make it easy on yourself, first fix the topology of your object to be all quads that flow together.

[image: Quad flow topology]

What this means is that you want the faces of your mesh to be squares instead of triangles where possible, because the subdivision will occur smoothly and predictably, and most importantly in this case - your UV unwraps will be much more clean and manageable.

[More on quad topology here.](http://blendernewbies.blogspot.jp/2008/11/3d-mesh-topology-tip-quads-vs-triangles.html)

### Addressing some problems specific to your model

There is an area with bad topology - faces are overlapping. Move these edge loops:

[image: Overlapping faces]

And here are the problems with your seams:

[image: UV seams problems]

Here is what I suggest doing instead to fix it:

[image: UV seams suggested solution]

### How I approached this

Now that you know a better way to place your seams, I should explain that for an unwrap as simple as this, you don't even need to use seams. You can simply select the faces you want and unwrap by section. Only selected faces will be unwrapped.

Select everything except the two end caps. Then do a UV unwrap using the 'Follow Active Quads' method. This method gives very clean results on topology consisting of long spans of quads.

[image: Follow Active Quads]

'Length Average' is the way to go to minimize texture distortion in this case, since it curves around corners.

[image: Length Average]

In the UV/Image Editor, scale your unwrap result down to fit within the square area.

Next, select only the two end cap faces, go into top view so you're looking at them straight-on, and UV unwrap again. This time choose 'Project From View'.

[image: UV Unwrap - Project From View]

Place your two unwrapped cap faces on your UV Map.

[image: The UV unwrap result, resized]

Here is the result:

[image: Sock Stripes]

If your texture looks strange on the tips you can Extrude the end caps so that the texture will be pulled in to a tiny point.

[image: Extrude and scale in the end cap faces]

You would want to do this if you were creating a candy cane, for example:

[image: Candy Cane]

[image]

Comment: Being the beginner I am I don't understand all of what you said so if you could maybe break it down for me. Thanks

Comment: Sure, I can go into more detail. Which parts specifically do you have questions about?

Comment: Could you go into detail with the start? The stuff about fixing the topology to be all quads? I should be ok with the rest

Comment: I elaborated a little more and added a link. Let me know if that clears it up for you. Topology can be a complex topic, but for your mesh nothing fancy is required - just know that squares are good. ;-)

Comment: I don't understand entirely because there are no triangles apart from the pointed tip and rounded bit at the other end and in your example you only changed the arch but I don't understand what to change on my one really

Comment: Hmmm, it's kind of hard from the screenshot to figure out what's happening with your topology that caused your UV unwrap to end up like that. Could you [upload your .blend](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)?

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=763" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/763/)

Comment: I just used smart UV unwrap cause I knew I would need some sort of help with the texturing

Comment: Please see the updated answer with additional explanation and screen shots.

Comment: Do I size it down as it is made?

Comment: You probably want to scale it to the right size before UV unwrapping, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: I mean size the UV unwrap down as it is

Comment: You can scale the UV layout, yes. Just select all or part of the mesh, then go to the UV/Image Editor and press S to scale as usual. There are cases when you must, if the UV layout extends beyond the square texture range.

Comment: I have unwrapped the model and sized it to all fit within the image editor. Can any improvements be made and how will I go about adding the candy cane stripes?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/S06ecPH.png

Comment: Yeah, you don't want the UV layout to be pinching to a triangular point like that. I'm not sure how it got that way, but if you unwrap using Follow Active Quads it shouldn't do that. Also, it looks like some faces may be overlapping in the UV layout. If you upload an updated .blend I'll take a look.

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=779" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/779/)

Comment: 1. I think doing Follow Active Quads while tris are selected produces that triangular distortion. Make sure only quads are selected when you unwrap. 2. You still haven't fixed your overlapping faces. 3. Continuity in your seam that spans the shaft remains broken as a result (examine it closely). 4. Your topology has poles where it hooks around, which is why you can't get a clean cylindrical unwrap and Follow Active Quads isn't working as you want it to - topologically it isn't forming a cylinder. Study the first screen shot in my answer to see what your topology should look like.

Comment: Im not understanding most of what your saying. Remember I just started Blender recently